# not able to consume soap based wcf service

Tags: wcf, post, soap

I am working on a soap based wcf service which need to accept an paremeter and then respond accordingly. I am getting following error when I am trying to consume it via test client:

**Value cannot be null. Parameter name:s**

```
interface:     

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/updateTimesheet?timesheetID={timesheetID}")]
[OperationContract]
string updateTimesheet(string timesheetID);
```

Implementing class:

```
public string updateTimesheet(string timesheet)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(timesheet);
    XmlNode xnodeTimeSheetHourID = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TimeSheetHourID");
    XmlNode xnodeHours = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TimeSheetHourID");
    return xnodeTimeSheetHourID.Value+" "+xnodeHours.Value;
}
```

web.config:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="postServiceBehavior" name="postService">
<endpoint address="http://172.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/postService.svc/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="IpostService">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

can some opne please help me how to resolve the error? I am quite sure that there is some issue in WebInvoke method but I am not able to catch it

Thanks

Pankaj

Comment: Your code implies that you are using a webHttpBinding so the updateTimesheet operation would return a JSON formatted response not soap. Could you please add your system.serviceModel configuration or WCF service configuration code to your answer?

Comment: Can you post the client code on how you are accessing the WCF Service

Comment: @SixtoSaez please check my updated code, I have added my web.config code here. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @Rajesh at the moment I am testing it with wcf test client

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file your endpoint definition is wrong:

It should have been something like below:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="postServiceBehavior" name="namespace.postService">
<endpoint address="http://172.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/postService.svc/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="namespace.IpostService">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Check the name and contract attributes in the service element and endpoint element respectively.

In order to get the proper one if you can post the complete skeleton of your interface class then i can give you what the value of the namespace should be.